# Spring Unsatisfied Dependency Exception, Error creating bean with name "Controller" when using Quartz Job Scheduler

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, spring-bean, xml-configuration

Quartz Config XML that i have:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 



 
<bean id="simpleJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
   <property name="jobClass" value="tn.companyName.package1.QuartzRunner"/>
 <property name="durability" value="true"></property>
</bean>





<bean id="simpleTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property  name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="3000" />
</bean>
<!-- Scheduler factory bean to glue together jobDetails and triggers to Configure Quartz Scheduler -->
<bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleJobDetail" />
        </list>
    </property>
 
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

i used a JobDetailFactoryBean and a SimpleTrigger, and then i glued them together in Scheduler Factory Bean.

this is the quartz runner class:

```java
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class QuartzRunner extends QuartzJobBean {
     
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
     
     

}
```

the problem extends to the creation of DAO and Service Beans.

I tried to add
`<property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />`
inside the Scheduler Factory Bean in the Quartz XML config but it didn't work.